# Unable to mount network block device using nbd-client

Tags: linux, mount, nbd

I am quite new to using nbd in general. I have written an nbdkit plugin in Rust that I have been using as an nbd server to read from a backing store, and have been using guestfish, a filesystem shell, as my client.

```
#!/bin/bash -
 guestfish --ro --format=raw -a nbd://localhost <<-EOF
  run
  mount /dev/sda /
  mount-local ./data
  mount-local-run
EOF
```

This has been working perfectly well for various filesystem types (xfs, ext2..4, FAT, etc), save for the fact that guestfish's mount commands are quite slow. So I am trying to remove it as a dependency and instead use the native linux `nbd-client` as a client.

```
> modprobe nbd
// no output
> sudo nbd-client localhost /dev/nbd0
//successfully connects
> sudo mkdir /mnt/nbd0
> sudo mount /dev/nbd0 /mnt/nbd0
mount: /mnt/nbd0: cannot mount /dev/nbd0 read-only.
```

I am not sure why this mount command is failing. I don't implement the write callback for nbdkit, so I do expect the files to be read-only, but I don't understand why this causes the mount to fail. I can instead run

```
sudo mount -o ro,noload /dev/nbd0 /mnt/nbd0
```

After which what occurs depends on the filesystem of the volume. My filesystem is ext4, for reference.

If the volume has a filesystem type other than ext4: `mount: /mnt/nbd0: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nbd0, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

If the volume has filesystem type ext4: the mount succeeds and I can enter directories, move around, etc, but **all of the files that I had in the volume are empty**. As in, when I mounted with guestfish, I could perform

```
cat dir0/textFile0.txt
"This is text file 0!"
```

And now performing the same `cat` command, or entering the text files with vim, shows that the files are completely empty.

Is this issue being caused by the `-o ro,noload` argument in the `mount` command? If so, how can I circumvent the error when trying to mount normally? If not, is there any known cause for such behavior? I know that my nbdkit plugin works because it is completely functional using guestfish, but using nbd-client  1. I am unable to mount anything but ext4 on my filesystem (even when adding `-t xfs` tag, for instance), and 2. file contents are completely erased.

Comment: why not use the readonly option for nbdclient? you can also try `-o loop,ro` utilizing the loop device is another layer that enforces readonly-ness. it may also be that nbdclient tries to use another feature not implemented by your server, what happens if you try with the regular nbd server?

Comment: @frostschutz It doesn't seem like adding the `-readonly` tag to the nbd-client changes anything unfortunately. I tried `-o ro,loop` and that returned `mount: /mnt/nbd0: cannot mount /dev/loop0 read-only.` I haven't tried connecting to nbd-client via nbd-server yet but I'll check that out and report back (I can't use nbd-server for my needs but it might tell us something anyway)

Comment: @frostschutz I followed the steps here unix.stackexchange.com/questions/658076/cannot-get-nbd-to-work to serve an xfs .img file with some test files on it and it successfully mounted. I was able to access all of the files, etc. I also served the same .img file using `nbdkit file <.img file>` (which is a provided nbdkit plugin) and was able to view the files normally.